# epson stylus sx230 wont scan

Tags: scanner

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 - and am a complete newbie. I can get my epson stylus sx 230 to print, but it wont scan. simple scan and skanlite cant find the scanner.
I tried downloading the .deb folders for iscan from the epson homepage and opening them with Gdebi but there doesn't seem to be any software called iscan or image scan in the ubuntu software center.
Can anybody help me getting my scanner to scan? Baby steps please!

:-)Andreas

Comment: What did you install? Open Terminal and type: dpkg -l | grep iscan

Answer (score 0):

Download this 2 packages:

iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb

iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb

from here:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=21580&DSCCHK=ea245da3525f56d8ca2ab9408ed2d6d8b481d435

Next install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb
```

[How can I get my Epson v500 scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11275/how-can-i-get-my-epson-v500-scanner-working)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried doing what you said. First I installed iscan-data_1.22.0-1_all.deb then I tried  typing uname -p x86_64 in terminal and got this reply" uname: ekstra operand 'x86_64'" Then i tried to install  iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb and got "wrong architecture" (i should mention that Iḿ using the 32 bit version) then i installed  iscan_2.29.1-5~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb

which went fine. As you can tell I'm completely new at solving this kind ofproblem, so a little further guidance would be greatly appreciated:-)